# Howto Build XCode5 Code Completion Hints

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, documentation-generation, code-completion, code-hinting

Trying to add Code Completion Hints to my own objective-c header files by checking some 3rd library headers.Looking if There is Code Completion Standarts in Xcode5 similar to VisualStudio.
I saw "//! description" (without quotas) working very well.

```
//! well seems working as a code completion hint
-(void)myMethod:(BOOL)myParam1 (NSString*)myParam2;
```

---

My Question 1: how can I add a linebreak ?

```
//! well seems working as a code completion hint
//! but this second line seems added into first description in code completion hint
-(void)myMethod:(BOOL)myParam1 (NSString*)myParam2;
```

---

My Question 2: looking for a standart similar to this

```
//! <method>myMethod:does something good.</method>
//! <param> (BOOL)myParam1:is first parameter </param>
//! <param> (NSString*)myParam2:is second parameter </param>
-(void)myMethod:(BOOL)myParam1 (NSString*)myParam2;
```

---

may you refer me a documentation about "//! description" (without quotas) how to ?
looking some standarts about "how to code add description standarts in xcode for objective-c"

(for sharing any ideas and knowledges;thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use javadoc format, which seems to work OK:

```
/**
 * Summary of method.
 *
 * A bit more detail, if you really must know stuff.
 *
 * @code
 * Some sample code.
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com
 *
 * @param p1 A parameter, no less.
 * @param p2 Another parameter.
 *
 * @return YES if it's Wednesday, else NO.
 */
```

See this [article](http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/comment-docs-in-xcode-5/) for more.